# Which resolv.conf is mandatory and how can I influence this?

Tags: networking, systemd, wifi, networkmanager, resolv.conf

When I use my home WiFi my Network Manager constantly loses connection to the right nameserver. It looks like it has lost the connection at all, but *disconnect* and *connect* manually gives me access to the internet at least for a few minutes.

Now I think I have a problem with my *resolv.conf* files.

Firstly, there are plenty of them.

```
find / -name "resolv.conf" ->

/lib/systemd/resolv.conf
/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
/etc/resolv.conf
```

Most of them are of course generated by systemd or NetworkManager and look like this (/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf)

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search speedport.ip # name of my router
nameserver 127.0.0.53 # sounds weird to me
```

But one, /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, looks like this:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver fe80::1%3
nameserver 192.168.2.1
search speedport.ip
```

My questions are:

1. Does anybody know, which of these files takes which role?
2. How can I make sure, that they all point to the same nameserver?
3. Can I decrease their number in order to be able to control less complexity?

Some entries from `journalctl --follow` look like this:

```
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>  [1546177758.3092] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: nm-dispatcher[6450]: req:3 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: nm-dispatcher[6450]: req:3 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: dhclient[6437]: DHCPACK of 192.168.2.100 from 192.168.2.1
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>  [1546177758.4251] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   address 192.168.2.100
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>  [1546177758.4251] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>  [1546177758.4252] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   gateway 192.168.2.1
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>    [1546177758.4252] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   lease time 1814400
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>  [1546177758.4252] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '192.168.2.1'
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>  [1546177758.4252] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   domain name 'speedport.ip'
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>  [1546177758.4252] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: avahi-daemon[1073]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.2.100.
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: avahi-daemon[1073]: New relevant interface wlp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: avahi-daemon[1073]: Registering new address record for 192.168.2.100 on wlp3s0.IPv4.
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>  [1546177758.4271] policy: set 'WLAN-235212' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: nm-dispatcher[6450]: req:4 'dhcp4-change' [wlp3s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: nm-dispatcher[6450]: req:4 'dhcp4-change' [wlp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: dhclient[6437]: bound to 192.168.2.100 -- renewal in 854872 seconds.
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: systemd[1]: Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>  [1546177758.5837] audit: op="statistics" arg="refresh-rate-ms" pid=2520 uid=1000 result="success"
Dez 30 14:49:18 name_machine: avahi-daemon[1073]: Registering new address record for 2003:ec:2bd0:b0a8:110f:592c:4811:b09a on wlp3s0.*.
Dez 30 14:49:19 name_machine: packagekitd[2722]: Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Dez 30 14:49:19 name_machine: packagekitd[2722]: Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Dez 30 14:49:19 name_machine: packagekitd[2722]: Done
Dez 30 14:49:19 name_machine: PackageKit[2722]: get-updates transaction /10897_cdbececd from uid 1000 finished with success after 442ms
Dez 30 14:49:19 name_machine: NetworkManager[1157]: <info>  [1546177759.9389] audit: op="statistics" arg="refresh-rate-ms" pid=2520 uid=1000 result="success"
Dez 30 14:54:17 name_machine: kernel: wlp3s0: AP bc:30:d9:8a:2e:8c changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 1 (2462/0 MHz)
```

where NetworkManager says: `dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '192.168.2.1'` and `dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   domain name 'speedport.ip'`.

I have no clue, whether this makes sense or how related `127.0.0.53` and `192.168.2.1` are to each other. Does `fe80::1%3` mean `127.0.0.53`? In this case how can I influence the order of nameservers in the given file? Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The standard file is `/etc/resolv.conf` but this may be a symlink.

e.g. on CentOS 7:

```
% ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 70 Dec  9 10:57 /etc/resolv.conf

% cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search spuddy.org
nameserver 10.0.0.134
```

On Debian 9

```
% ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Dec 21 23:05 /etc/resolv.conf -> /var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf

% cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search spuddy.org
nameserver 10.0.0.134
```

Now 127.0.0.53 is a special entry for `systemd-resolved`, which is a stub DNS listener provided by `systemd` and will act as a DNS server for your machine.  So it *is* possible that this is the correct DNS entry for your machine.

You may be able to tell what server you are using with a command such as `nslookup` or `dig`

```
% nslookup www.google.com
Server:     10.0.0.134
Address:    10.0.0.134#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.google.com
Address: 216.58.217.100

% dig www.google.com | grep SERVER
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.134#53(10.0.0.134)
```

In both cases we can see I'm using `10.0.0.134` to do the DNS resolution.

`fe80::1` is just a "link local" IPv6 address, rather than an IPv4 address.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. It has turned out that 127.0.0.53 *is* my nameserver (due to `nslookup` and `dig`). My `/etc/resolv.conf` links to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`, which looks OK. But which role plays `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, which says `nameserver 192.168.2.1`? Do I need to fix it?

Comment: Or is it rather [the other way round (127.0.0.53 in nslookup is based on a systemd-bug)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973017/wrong-nameserver-set-by-resolvconf-and-networkmanager)? But this question is more than one year old now.

Comment: Looks like people are still being hit by that issue; the last post was a few weeks ago.  Only the file `/etc/resolv.conf` (and where it links to) is in active use.  You can switch to using the systemd/resolve entry (which points to your router) with `sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf ; sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`  - this tells your machine to ignore the local systemd-resolved stub resolver and use the value sent by the DHCP server... which is probably the right one to use, anyway!

Comment: This made things even worse. Now I have no address resoultion over wifi anymore. I think I need to figure out, what this *192.168.2.1* actually is or does.

Comment: Odds are 192.168.2.1 is your router

Comment: Well, the last problem was due to the fact that I tried two solutions in parallel and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/973025/336234) did not work at all, it leads to an unknown nameserver (in my case). Now I'm trying your solution only.